# How can I convert an array of digits into an interger in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I convert an array of 6 integers into a single integer. Example provided below of what I want to do.

Array: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Integer:  123456

Thank you!

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: That's not an Array™

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using join and Number**

Read here first before using [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number),  [Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join),  [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

```js
let arr =[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

let op = Number(arr.join(''))

console.log(op);
```

Comment: Please do not redefine global objects like Array! Try console.log(Array.isArray([])) in your code after that.

Comment: @ValeryBaranov i copied variable part from question itself. changed now.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be:

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const int = parseInt(arr.join(""), 10);
console.log(int)
```

From MDN Number page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number :

Number.parseInt() The value is the same as parseInt() of the global object.

Added radix argument, as @Bergi pointed out. Although in this case js engine [will assume it is 10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: Don't forget to pass a radix argument to `parseInt`

Answer (score 0):

This logic takes a running total.  Starting at zero, for every number, multiply the total by ten to shift it to the next higher order, and then add the integer.

```js
var data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var result = data.reduce(function(total, integer){
  return total * 10 + integer;
}, 0);

console.log(result);
```